# The New Art of Defense in Chess vs The Art Defense in Chess

Tags: books, positional-play

Is The New Art of Defense in Chess or The Art Defense in Chess better? I am 1900 on an upward trend.

Comment: Can you provide us with more details, e.g. your playing strength, general strengths & weaknesses?

Comment: Is it an older and a newer version of the same book by the same author, or am I mistaken somehow? Then the books are probably quite similar in contents, and it shouldn't matter too much which one you choose, aside from some variations checked with computer analysis. I would say go with the newer one, unless you have a good price on the older version.

Comment: @Scounged according to the author it is very different from the older one with newer examples and newer ideas

Comment: @Jimmy360 Yeah, authors tend to claim such things about the newer editions of their own books, I wonder why ;)

But reading customer reviews, this actually seems to be the case. One thing you may want to consider is whether you can stand the old English notation. Otherwise the old book may not be a very good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the new book is quite different to the old one:

> On the whole, however, *The New Art of Defense in Chess* **should be seen as a fundamentally new book**. This is because Soltis recognizes the way in which dynamism and activity have become fundamental to modern defensive techniques.

Source: [ChessBookReviews](https://chessbookreviews.wordpress.com/tag/new-art-of-defence-in-chess/), emphasis is mine.

Synthesising the review, the reasons why the book is different is because:

- Computer analysis has helped players find flaws in the attack in postmortems, which they use to improve their defensive technique
- Players are more open to playing 'ugly', counter intuitive moves that are based on concrete analysis
- After Tal's reign as world champion, players realised that active defensive is usually better than passive defence